# Working with Connection string

Tags: c#, web-config

My below code sample is working fine, but I would like to add my client credentials into the web.config file (i.e, Inside the connection string).

I tried but had no luck. Can anyone please help?

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    

        // Organisation service URL
        var organizationUri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CrmConnectionStr"].ConnectionString);

        //Client credentials
        var credentials = new ClientCredentials();
        credentials.UserName.UserName = @"domain\username";  
        credentials.UserName.Password = "password";


        // Use the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online connection string from the web.config file named "CrmConnectionStr".
                    using (OrganizationServiceProxy _service = new OrganizationServiceProxy(organizationUri, null, credentials, null))
        {
     Response.Write("Connected");
        }
    }
```

**Web.config file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="CrmConnectionStr"  connectionString="https://test.domain.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc" />     
 </connectionStrings>
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with dynamics, so forgive me if this is way off. Have you checked out? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681567.aspx . It looks like you might be able to add it in. Scroll down to the "The following example shows the connection string using Active Directory authentication:" section

Comment: connection string is a database connection string.  Others would be application settings - research that namespace instead

Comment: That is not a connectionstring. Your string is the url to a webservice. A connectionstring is a string that may be used to connect to a RDMS (database system such as SQL Server or Oracle)

Comment: One other note, you might look at configuration section if you have more complex needs.

Answer (score 2):

As RandomWebGuy pointed out you could be connecting to Microsoft Dynamics CRM in which case you could just change your connection string to include the username etc like this `connectionString="https://test.domain.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc; Username=Fred.Bloggs; Password=P@ssword;"`

However, if you connecting to a webservice or want to store arbitrary values such as URIs, usernames, passwords etc then use the **AppSettings** section, not **ConnectionString**.

So, something like this in your config file:

```
<appSettings>  
    <add key="UserName" value="Fred.Bloggs" />
    <add key="Password" value="P@ssword" />
    <add key="ServiceUri" value="https://test.domain.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc />
</appSettings>
```

And then in code:

```
var organizationUri = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceUri"]);

// ...

credentials.UserName.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
credentials.UserName.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
```

Comment: But OP ask about to add it to the connection strings. OP only needs to change connection string to make it work?

Comment: No, he uses the word connection string incorrectly in his question. He is actually connecting to a webservice so should use AppSettings.

Comment: @Belogix I don't think this is correct. Is he not talking about this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695810.aspx

Comment: Thank you RandomWebGuy, I must admit I skimmed the code and saw .SVC so just assumed he was using arbitrary web service. I've left my original answer there for completeness to show using AppSettings but updated to show including in ConnectionString.

Comment: Thank you all for giving your answers-I added my username and password in the connection string, also I would like to know how can we separate them to pass the arguments as below,           using (OrganizationServiceProxy _service = new OrganizationServiceProxy(organizationUri, null, credentials, null))
             and write in code please.... It will be the same way suggested by Belogix or someother way please suggest.

Comment: If you want to pass in by code then you will want to use AppSettings as explained in the second part of my answer (my code example should do exactly what you are after I believe).

Comment: @Kittu, if that answers your question please click on the tick next to this answer to mark it as correct. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom configuration to store your specific data (and do not try to piggy back on the existing connection strings area, which has an exact format).

Here is an example:
[How to include simple collections in ConfigurationSection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699047/how-to-include-simple-collections-in-configurationsection/3366402#3366402)

This is much better than having several disjointed AppSetting(s) values.
Everything germane to your values is encapsulated into a known area.