# Allow User Input To Determine SQL Server Connection String

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

As the application I am developing requires access to more than one server, I want to allow the user to select the 'site' they wish to access from a drop-down list and for the connection string to updated accordingly.

I've had two ideas (Pseudo-code);

```
IF (drop-down value = Site2)
{string connectionString = "Server=server2; Database=db......"}

ELSE IF(drop-down value = Site3.....
```

Or;

```
string @server = drop-down value;

string connectionString = "Server=@server; Database=db......"
"pass connection variable??"
```

Which of these methods is best? Or is there a more efficient alternative?

I'm unsure about how to pass a variable to the connection string (Option 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    string ConnectionString;
    switch (comboBox1.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            ConnectionString = "Data Source=server1;Initial Catalog=database1;User ID=user1;Password=password1";
            break;
        case 1:
            ConnectionString = "Data Source=server2;Initial Catalog=database2;User ID=user1;Password=password2";
            break;
        case 3:
            ConnectionString = "Data Source=server3;Initial Catalog=database3;User ID=user1;Password=password3";
            break;
    }
    SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    Con.Open();
```

Comment: Where do you get them from, then?  User entered?

Comment: @granadaCoder Values are selected from a drop down - I don't want the user to enter their server of choice.

Comment: DUDE, please don't hard code connection strings, even if the only difference is the servername........The guy who inherits your code down the road will HATE you.

Comment: So you never test your code in a QA environment?  Just straight to production?  How do you handle different environments after the code is built?.............Wow.

Comment: No this doesn't go straight into production, who ever said it did? Settle down.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx).

For instance

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = /* your server here */;
builder.InitialCatalog = "db";
/* etc.... */
var connString = builder.ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need "super dynamic", then Davio has the correct one.

If you need "I got N number of databases, that may change from time to time", then I suggest:

The below is typical Dot Net 2.0 and above configuration.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="EastCoastConnectionString" connectionString="server=server01;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
<add name="WestCoastConnectionString" connectionString="server=server02;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And then create a custom configuration section that will map a "friendly name" to a connection string.

Find this code:
[How to include simple collections in ConfigurationSection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699047/how-to-include-simple-collections-in-configurationsection/3366402#3366402)

```
  <TransformationToDirectoryMappingsSection>
    <TransformationToDirectoryMappings>
      <add FriendlyName="NY Giants" PickupFolder="EastCoastConnectionString" />
      <add FriendlyName="NE Patriots" PickupFolder="EastCoastConnectionString" />
      <add FriendlyName="Carolina Panthers" PickupFolder="EastCoastConnectionString" />

      <add FriendlyName="San Francisco 49ers" PickupFolder="WestCoastConnectionString" / >
      <add FriendlyName="Seattle Seahawks" PickupFolder="WestCoastConnectionString" />
      <add FriendlyName="Arizona Cardinals" PickupFolder="WestCoastConnectionString" />
    </TransformationToDirectoryMappings>
  </TransformationToDirectoryMappingsSection>
</configuration >
```

Then populate a drop down box with all the "FriendlyName"'s.......and then you can map that back to a connection string.

Now, you could just populate the drop down lists with the name of the connection strings......but I don't like that idea...............I prefer a "friendly name" to "actual name" mapping.

---

At the very least, setup the Connection-Strings in your config file....., and populate your drop down with this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx

```
  ConnectionStringSettingsCollection connections = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;

    foreach (ConnectionStringSettings connection in connections)
    {
      string name = connection.Name;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using SqlConnectionStringBuilder, I would wrap the display name and the connection string in a nested class in the forms.
Like this (in the form/user control):

```
    private void PopulateComboBox(ComboBox comboBox)
    {
        var items = new[]
            {
                new ConnectionListItem {DisplayName = "Site 1", ConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder("Server=...")},
                new ConnectionListItem {DisplayName = "Site 2", ConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder("Server=...")},
            };

        comboBox.Items.AddRange(items);

    }

    class ConnectionListItem
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public SqlConnectionStringBuilder ConnectionString { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return DisplayName;
        }
    }
```