# Advantages/disadvantages of configSection vs plain xml?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc-3

It seems like an awful lot of added complexity, extra work, and extra files to implement a custom config section in an asp.net project. That being said, what makes it worth it vs just reading config information out of an xml file (or some other source)? Is it more performant? Is it best practice?

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but isn't the config just a plain XML? How is it different from a regular XML?

Comment: @Gray The web.config is plain XML, but setting up a custom "configSection" requires jumping through a bunch of extra hoops.

Comment: it is based on XML Markup, but it has a layer of being able to configure the behaviour of a site.
just like to say "HTML is plain XML!" etc

Comment: @TomerW Ah, thank you for the analogy. That makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: Advantage: `(MyconfigSection)Configuration.GetSection("sectionName")`. Gives you strongly typed access and intellisense.

Comment: I've done the custom configuration in a file, where you just deserialize the XML or JSON into a static field and read from that. I'll admit, it's nice, because you don't have to write any real code, but in the grand scheme of things, it doesn't take all that long to do it properly, and you'll get built-in validation on application start, consistency, config transformations, and all the other nice things that these answers are talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you can create an "object" that holds the values (from custom config) vs a bunch of disjoint scalars.

It also allows the config values to be help in a seperate file (a trick I really like).

Aka, I put all my SmtpSettings in a ~separate SmtpSettings.config file.  And I keep "app.config" or "web.config" leaner, and I don't accientally overwrite values.

PS

And if you do it the "DotNet" way, a future developer won't have to learn a custom xml routine, aka, its more consistent project to project vs "do whatever works" and whoever inherits your code will thank you instead of curse you.

```
  <connectionStrings configSource="ExternalConnectionStrings.config" />
```

then the contents of the file ExternalConnectionStrings.config

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add (blah blah blah) />

</connectionStrings>
```

REMEMBER.  You'll have to use a POST-BUILD event to copy this file (or other "trick"), it is not auto copied like app.config .

It should work for "custom" handlers as well.

```
  <configSections>

    <section name="FactoryMappingSettingsSection" type="MyConfigClassHandler, MyCompany.Framework.CrossDomain.Configuration"/>


  </configSections>
```

then later:

```
  <FactoryMappingSettingsSection configSource="FactoryMappingSettings.config"/>
```

Comment: how do you do the seperate files thing ? can you split everything? like Connection strings ? References?

Comment: Thanks... i love splitting things in files :) didn't know about the configSource attribute.

Comment: Yep.  I almost never have an "environment config accidental overwrite" issue using this method.  And 99% of config values is getting them correct...for the environment in question.

Comment: Here is an example, BTW:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699047/how-to-include-simple-collections-in-configurationsection/3366402#3366402

Answer (score 0):

well, that's a good question i think.

i think the only advantage is that it is known to .NET developers, so they dont need to learn the new tricks one implements in his own solution

maybe a bit of security too, because the server protects web.config files but dont care to send an XML file.