# Load string collection from external data in C#

Tags: c#, collections

I have a class that has a collection of strings that is used to validate values before storing them.  The declaration for the collection looks like this:

```
public readonly System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection RetentionRange =
            new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection() 
            { "NR", "AR", "PE", "EX", "LI", "TE", "FR" };
```

I'd like to maintain the list of valid codes outside of the compiled class.  How do I go about that?  BTW, there's no requirement for the strings to be limited to two characters, they just happen to be in the current scheme.

EDIT: By "external data" I mean something like a config file.

Comment: you could always serialize the class or collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a `StringCollection` in the [`AppSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx).

Each value is separated by a new line.

Here's a screenshot (german IDE but it might be helpful anyway)

[image]

You can read it in this way:

```
var myStringCollection = Properties.Settings.Default.MyCollection;
foreach (String value in myStringCollection)
{ 
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Why App Setting, why not XML or an structured text file, or maybe the database if the OP has one ?

Comment: @JAX: why not a database? There are many ways to store something. But i have not the time to provide all. Also, OP has mentioned StringCollection which is the only collection which can be used in the app-settings by default. And OP has also mentioned that he wants to use a configuration file. You can edit this collection without needing to recompile since it's stored in a xml file.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're suggesting, and unfortunately my German isn't good enough to unwind what I'm seeing in the screenshot.  :\

Comment: I just wanted know the reason why you chose app setting, and thanks for clarifying that to me. My curiosity, no disrespect though :)

Comment: Figured out where to find what you're showing.  Now just to figure out how to load the string collection...

Comment: @J.D.Ray: why do you need to "load" it at all? If you can load it you have already something where it is stored, then i don't understand the requirement. Normally you create the setting, add some strings manually and then you can access it wherever you need it. They are loaded and cached automatically.

Comment: The list of strings is a valid list of values for a field.  Right now I'm using 

    `if (RetentionRange.Contains(value)) { // go ahead }
    else { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException }`

I want implementers to be able to change the valid value list without re-constructing the code.

Comment: @J.D.Ray: so the list is not the same application-wide and can be changed programmatically? It's still nor clear for what it's used and where/when it can be changed. You can change apllication-settings programmatically if they are not application-wide settings but user-settings. Just read the documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think I've got it: `RetentionRange.AddRange(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("DisposalRangeValues"));`  I'll test it on Monday.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Storing it in a text file is an option.

**How to store:**

```
    var dir = @"somedirectory\textfile.txt";

    var text = string.Join(",",RetentionRange.Cast<string>());
    File.WriteAllText(dir,text);
```

**How to retrieve:**

```
var text= File.ReadAllText(@"somedirectory\textfile.txt");
foreach(var str in text.Split(","))
    RetentionRange.Add(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

The right answer to your question depends a great deal on why you want to store the strings outside the assembly.

Assuming the reason you want this is because the collection of strings is expected to change over time, I would suggest you create your own `System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection` implementation that defines one of the elements as a `System.Configuration.ConfigurationElementCollection` instance. If this is a tad too complicated for your requirements, then an appSettings key with a value consisting of a comma separated list of strings (from which you would build your `StringCollection` at runtime) might actually be a better solution.

[The answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699047/how-to-include-simple-collections-in-configurationsection) have examples of both approaches.